# Multiple Sheets merged into one excluding few sheets. Error

Tags: excel, merge

I have ran this macro however it is copying every worksheet available, even I have mentioned not to copy the particular worksheets.

```
Sub Combine()

Dim J As Integer
Dim ws As Worksheet

On Error Resume Next

If ws.Name <> "Invoicing" And ws.Name <> "Master Data" Then
    Sheets(1).Select
    Worksheets.Add
    Sheets(1).Name = "Combined"
    Sheets(2).Activate
    Range("A1").EntireRow.Select
    Selection.Copy Destination:=Sheets(1).Range("A1")
End If
For J = 2 To Sheets.Count
    Sheets(J).Activate
    Range("A1").Select
    Selection.CurrentRegion.Select
    Selection.Offset(1, 0).Resize(Selection.Rows.Count - 1).Select
    Selection.Copy Destination:=Sheets(1).Range("A65536").End(xlUp)(2)
Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You've defined ws as a worksheet, but haven't specified which worksheet, you then cycle through each sheet except the first.

Try this code - it cycles through each sheet, but ignores certain named sheets.

```
Sub Combine()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim shtMaster As Worksheet
Dim rTargetLastCell As Range
Dim rSourceLastCell As Range

Set shtMaster = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Master Data")

'Cycle through each worksheet in the workbook.
'NB: Worksheets exclude chart sheets and macro sheets.
For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    Select Case ws.Name
        Case "Invoicing", "Master Data"
            'Do Nothing
        Case Else
            'Find the last cell containing data in the two sheets.
            Set rTargetLastCell = LastCell(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Master Data"))
            Set rSourceLastCell = LastCell(ws)

            'Copy and paste the relevant data.
            With ws
                .Range(.Cells(2, 1), rSourceLastCell).Copy _
                    Destination:=shtMaster.Cells(rTargetLastCell.Row + 1, 1)
            End With
    End Select
Next ws

End Sub

Public Function LastCell(wrkSht As Worksheet) As Range

    Dim lLastCol As Long, lLastRow As Long

    On Error Resume Next

    With wrkSht
        lLastCol = .Cells.Find("*", , , , xlByColumns, xlPrevious).Column
        lLastRow = .Cells.Find("*", , , , xlByRows, xlPrevious).Row

        If lLastCol = 0 Then lLastCol = 1
        If lLastRow = 0 Then lLastRow = 1

        Set LastCell = .Cells(lLastRow, lLastCol)
    End With
    On Error GoTo 0

End Function
```